# laravel: login on front page? Should I use two controllers?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

So I've worked through the foundations of laravel. But for my own project, there will be a login on the front page, along with obviously other stuff.

So here, I'm torn to, should I use a single controller to deal with the frontpage and the auth? Or can I somehow use two controllers to simplify the look and feel of the code? Is there another way to somehow embed the logins cript on the front page. Like a jquery fetch /loginpage/ for a div?

So my question is, what is a standard and good way to deal with a auth system from the front page, when there are also other things to load on the page?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends and it's a broad question (IMO).

Comment: what can I search to learn more about this?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.google.com.bd/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=service%20oriented%20architecture%20php).

Comment: Are you looking for a package to help with this at all?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Thanks for the attempt to help. I know now that stackoverflow only works if you have actual code to troubleshoot. Reddit did a better job answering this.

I really don't need to know more about php service oriented programming to get this done. I'm sure it's a "broad" question, but I am asking for a standard way to put a login on the front page. It is specific enough. I'm sorry, this community has helped me a lot, but I don't get why this community is very negative to non-code specific questions...

https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/3s0u7x/dealing_with_login_on_frontpage/

Reddit solved my problem.